# Is there a "2015" section to the Back to the Future hub?

Tags: lego-dimensions

In the Back to the Future free-roam hub, I've found a time travel point to travel from 1985 back to 1885.

Is there an equivalent area set in 2015?  If so, how do I get to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are two Time Accelerator Switches in the 1985 Town Square, not just one.

The first, just in front of the Town Hall / Clock Tower, takes you to 1885:
[image]

The second, in front of Maxom, takes you to 2015:
[image]

The spots to return to 1985 in each case are in the equivalent location.